# chrome development console only gives me undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, undefined

I am testing some JS and when I try to get the output in the console I only get "Undefined" Can anyone assist?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncu3H.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Make sure that whenever you post code/logs/errors/etc., it must always be in TEXT FORM. Here's [why you shouldn't use images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14469685). Please [edit] your question to fix this. Thank you! See this help center article on [ask].

Answer (score 0):

There are a few improvements that can be made before your code works.

1. `var upperCaseFirstChar = firstChar.toUpperCase` is wrong. It should be `.toUpperCase()`. The difference is that your code assigns the variable to a **function** while the new one assigns it to the return **value** of the function, in this case an uppercase character.
2. `name.slice(1, name.length)` is redundant. The slice function will automatically use the full string length in a second parameter is not supplied. Use this: `name.slice(1)`.

After that is done, let's get to your question. The reason it doesn't return anything is because you don't tell it to! All that happens in that code block is the definition of variables. What you actually want is to place `capitaliseName` at the end of your code, like this:

```js
var name = prompt("Whats your name?");
var firstChar = name.slice(0,1);
var upperCaseFirstChar = firstChar.toUpperCase();
var restOfName = name.slice(1);
var capitaliseName = upperCaseFirstChar + restOfName;

capitaliseName;
```

That should return the value that you want.

Resources:

- [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) on MDN.